# cannot get opengraph to scape url

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I know this is a pretty common problem but any of the solutions I have tried (thats a lot) haven't worked.

I am trying to scrape http://residencyradio.com/ using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fresidencyradio.com%2F

The site itself is getting a complete overhaul, this will be revealed next week and I want the relevant images, title and info to appear if someone links to the site, but instead at the moment these properties are being shown as they were the very first time the site was cached on FB (nearly a year ago).

As far as I can see, I have included all the relevant meta tags etc how they should be, I even tried implementing a like button on the site, but to no avail. I have followed what has been set out on: http://ogp.me/ and can't see anything wrong.

Here is a sippet of the page from `!DOCTYPE` to `</head>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>The Residency</title>

<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
    </script>
<![endif]-->
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />


<!--Meta Data-->
<meta name="keywords" content="The Residency, M. Budden, Neal McClelland, Michael Budden, Radio, Residency Radio, 
Residency, Global, House, Electro, Progressive, Tech, Techno, DnB, Drum and Base, Dubstep, iTunes, Belfast, 
Northern Ireland, UK" /> 
<meta name="description" content="Brought to you by Neal McClelland and M. Budden, The Residency is a weekly global underground dance show" />
<meta property="og:title" content="The Residency A global underground dance show" />
<meta property="og:type" content="musician" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.facebook.com/theresidency" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.residencyradio.com/images/Residency_logo_circle.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The Residency" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1324839758" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been scratching my head for a few days trying to figure it out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strange, when I try to debug it I get: "Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess, but your html is not valid and maybe because of that the facebook scraper fail to parse and extract the data from it.

I haven't went through all of it, but you don't seem to close all tags.
For example the description and keywords meta tags don't end with "/>" or ">".

---

## Edit

Screen capture of what the debugger shows when I load your html from my server:
[image: Screen Capture]

Comment: yes you're right, these tags weren't closed properly, I've now rectified this but it still makes no difference :/

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, I keep getting that error with the Debug tool. I saved the exact page on my server and tried the debugger on that and it returned the right data. Looks like facebook can't reach your server but I have no idea why.

Comment: oh, how strange! I will have to contact my provider about that, couldn't find anything that was wrong. Thanks for the help dude!

Comment: do you by any chance have a screen grab of what it shows you? I can get it to scrape info for http://residencyradio.com/index.html but its giving me a 406 response.